# How to hide save as and tags fields in NSSavepanel

Tags: objective-c, macos, nssavepanel

I am trying to create a custom save panel, I can add my fields and checkboxes with the `accessoryView` property of `NSSavePanel` but I also want to hide the default save as label field and Tags label and field like in the picture[image] Is there any way to do this?

The screenshot from  [json accelerator](http://nerdery.com/json-accelerator) app. Is it `NSSavepanel` or any other control?

Answer (score 0):

Finally realized that its not `NSSavePanel` its `NSOpenPanel`

```
    NSOpenPanel* openDlg = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
    [openDlg setCanChooseFiles:NO];
    [openDlg setCanCreateDirectories:YES];
    [openDlg setCanChooseDirectories:YES];
NSView *view = [[NSView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 0, 100)];
    openDlg.accessoryView = view;
    [openDlg beginSheetModalForWindow:self.window completionHandler:^(NSInteger result) {
        NSLog(@"%ld",(long)result);
    }];
```